# WPF - Datagrid placeholder hide inputted text from textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a simple datagrid with CanUserAddRows enabled:

I have a textbox to input total at column Total in Datagrid Placeholder, but whenever I'm done inputting, the value is hidden like there's an invisible watermark or something.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgReceivables" Margin="8,98,10,91" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    KeyUp="dgReceivables_KeyUp" GridLinesVisibility="None" CellEditEnding="dgReceivables_CellEditEnding"
              LoadingRow="dgReceivables_LoadingRow" TextInput="dgReceivables_TextInput" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">


    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="TOTAL 2" Width="Auto">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBox x:Name="txtTotal" Text="{Binding Total,StringFormat={}{0:0.00}}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

[Inputting sample value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfuzM.png)

[AFter lost focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VexE.png)

Comment: Can you add more information in your question?

Comment: @ManishDubey please see the image link I add. When I select other cell after inputting something on my textbox, the inputted text becomes hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You are missing `CellTemplate`.

### Why?

If, for instance, instead of overriding, you would've used a `DataGridTextColumn` column, the `DataGird` would've known that the data contained is Text (a string). 
In such a case the `DataGird` would've used a `TextBlock` and a `TextBox` as `CellTemplate` and `CellEditingTemplate` respectively.

**By overriding** `DataGridTemplateColumn` **you completely replaced the columns behavior**. This means that the `DataGrid` is **unable to determine how the data in the column has to be displayed/edited**. It still might be a string, but that doesn't mean you actually interpret that string as such, it might be the path to an image that you wish to display as such in the `DataGrid`.

**Since you only provided** `CellEditingTemplate` **the DataGrid now knows how to edit** the data in that column, **but not how to display** it.

### Solution

When overriding `DataGridTemplateColumn` you need to provide *at least* `CellTemplate`, as this defines how the data in that column needs to be interpreted (displayed). If you wish the column only to display data, this is all you need to do.

Try this:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="TOTAL 2" Width="Auto">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Total, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtTotal" Text="{Binding Total,StringFormat={}{0:0.00}}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

**NOTE: Code is untested!**

Comment: Just wanted to post something similar :)

Comment: @GabrielYap, WPF complicated things in some way, yes. But I think it's only natural. Most powerful, aka flexible, systems, tend to increase in complexity. I'll elaborate in my answer.

Comment: @GabrielYap it's not WPF that's complicating things, it is you who chose `DataGridTemplateColumn` instead of `DataGridTextColum` and thus you had to write two templates instead of nothing ;)

Comment: @GabrielYap, edited the answer, don't have much time now, sorry if the explanation isn't that good.